# Pushing file list from folder Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I have a function that lists all files in a folder. I am having trouble pushing out the files through the array. I'm not sure where I went wrong. When I export the module and run it I get an error.

```
const getfiles = (callback) => {
        const filesx = []

            fs.readdir(dire, function (err, fileNames) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("you have an error.")
        }


        fileNames.forEach(file => {
            let filee = file.text()

            filesx.push({
                filee
            })
        })


    })
    callback({
        filesx
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getfiles
}
```

The error I get is

```
report-app\src\util\getfolder.js:24
        filesx
        ^

ReferenceError: filesx is not defined
```

Comment: I'd expect `dire` to not be defined... anyway, `fs.readdir` is async, so you need to move your callback call into the `readdir` callback. Also, `fileNames` is going to be an array of filenames, i.e. strings, those don't have a `.text()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to trade

```
fs.readdir(dire, function (err, fileNames) {});
```

for

```
fs.readdir(dire, (err, fileNames) => {});
```

This possible that this function don't have access to these outside, arrow functions would already solve.

Comment: it works, but Is there a reason I am not seeing the file now? I am printing like so `files.getfiles(folderResult => {console.log(folderResult.filesx})`

Comment: try to use:
`for(let file of fileNames) {}`
maybe he is running callback before generating the list.
I've had problems with this before

Comment: I think I am storing the file wrong. ` let filee = file` Any way to just store it ? The array seems empty

Comment: try

`const filesx = []
fs.readdir(dire, (err, fileNames) => {
    if (files === undefined) {
        alert('Not found');
        return false;
    }

    if (fileNames.length > 0) {
        for(let file of fileNames) {
            filesx.push(path + file);
        });
    }
});`